# ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 26 elements, new values have 25 elements ​

Tags: python, pandas

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-70b2451ab305> in <module>
      6 
      7 headers = ["symboling","normalized-losses","make","fuel-type","aspiration","num-of-doors","body-style","drive-wheels","engine-location","wheel-base","length","width","height","curb-weight","engine-type","num-of-cylinders","engine-size","fuel-system","bore","stroke","compresstion-ratio","hosepower""peak-rpm","city=mpg","highway-mpg","price"]
----> 8 df.columns = headers
      9 df.head(5)
     10 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __setattr__(self, name, value)
   5152         try:
   5153             object.__getattribute__(self, name)
-> 5154             return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
   5155         except AttributeError:
   5156             pass

pandas/_libs/properties.pyx in pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.__set__()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _set_axis(self, axis, labels)
    562     def _set_axis(self, axis: int, labels: Index) -> None:
    563         labels = ensure_index(labels)
--> 564         self._mgr.set_axis(axis, labels)
    565         self._clear_item_cache()
    566 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in set_axis(self, axis, new_labels)
    225         if new_len != old_len:
    226             raise ValueError(
--> 227                 f"Length mismatch: Expected axis has {old_len} elements, new "
    228                 f"values have {new_len} elements"
    229             )

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 26 elements, new values have 25 elements
```

**Here is the code:**

```py
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/autos/imports-85.data'

df = pd.read_csv(url, header = None)

headers = \["symboling","normalized-losses","make","fuel-type","aspiration","num-of-doors","body-style","drive-wheels","engine-location","wheel-base","length","width","height","curb-weight","engine-type","num-of-cylinders","engine-size","fuel-system","bore","stroke","compresstion-ratio","hosepower""peak-rpm","city=mpg","highway-mpg","price"\]

df.columns = headers
df.head(5)
df.dtypes
df.describe()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your index is incorrect it contains 25 elements for 26 columns it's the reason of the error.

```py
df.shaphe
# (205, 26)

len(headers)
# 25
```

To fix it

- `"hosepower""peak-rpm","city=mpg"` -> `"hosepower","peak-rpm","city-mpg"`
- Remove also the `\` surrounding the index